# autenticação asmx

Tags: oauth2, asmx

Tenho um webservice em asmx que contem funçoes de insert, delete, update, select, estou consumindo ele via ajax, porque minha aplicação nao pode trabalhar de lado do servidor. Minha duvida é como posso prover autenticação para conectar nesse webservice? Cheguei a colocar Login e senha em cada função porem em javascript e html nao tem como esconder essa senha, vou ter que passar via parametros para acessar e entao quem ver o codigo da pagina pode ver o login e senha.
Pesquisando no stack encontrei esse link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734397/using-an-oauth-access-token-to-access-soap-service, porém não consegui entender seu funcionamento dentro do meu webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de pesquisar, entendi que asmx está obsoleto, a miscrosoft deixa essa opção no Visual Studio apenas porque é 'legado', estou desenvolvendo em WebApi que é muito simples e com muito mais opções. 
Encontrei esse site que fala de segurança em Restful, e cita as opções que podemos utilizar para implementar isso(em Web Api claro), muito esclarecedor:

http://blog.rivendel.com.br/2013/06/07/seguranca-em-apis-rest-parte-1/